Multi-Threading instance getters
I am working with a grpc application which uses interfaces to interact with multiple different classes of objects.
My main class looks like this:
    private IInterfacedControl _interfaceControl;
    public IInterfacedControl GetInterfacedControl() => _interfaceControl

When I need to access this Control in the GRPC services methods I call GetInterfacedControl().SomeProperty. My problem comes in that I am trying to synchronize the property values of calls from similar times. two calls that come in at the same time. Some of the calls effect multiple aspects of the class. Is there anyway I can synchronize the whole class that is IInterfacedControl to keep the variables updated across all threads?
I have attempted to synchronize in the class itself some of the variables and methods but have still run into the separate calls class properties having different values.
Edit for more information
The issue I am currently having involves two method calls:

periodically checks for whether a service is connected via a stored variable (IsConnected) in the Interfaced class.
 public override Task<IsConnectedResponse> IsConnected(IsConnectedRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
 {
     var isConnected = _factory.GetInterfacedControl().IsConnected;
     LogService.LogCallersGetter(isConnected.ToString());
     return Task.FromResult(new IsConnectedResponse { IsConnected = isConnected });
 }


Attempts to connect to the service.
 public override Task<ConnectResponse> AttemptConnect(ConnectRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
 {
     string action = $"Connect?: {request.Connect}";
     LogService.LogCallers(action);
     try
     {
         _factory.GetInterfacedControl().Connect(request.Connect);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);
     }
     return Task.FromResult(new ConnectResponse { });
 }



The service in question is a 3rd party application that connects to my app via wcf.
When the service connects to my application, usually while one or both of the method calls is running. Each of the threads have a different instance of the interfaced class.
All 3 points of entry make a call to RaiseUpdateConnected which overwrites the IsConnected property. One of those calls is an explicit RaiseUpdateConnected(false) if we think we aren't connected.
    internal void RaiseUpdateConnected(bool isConnected)
    {
        IsConnected = isConnected;
        EUpdateConnected?.Invoke(this, isConnected); 
    }

This is my class connect method. The event beacon is subscribed to when the service establishes a connection to my app. I tried putting a lock here and when the app and service connect to synchronize eventBeacon not being null.
    public void Connect()
    {           
        eventBeacon?.Invoke(null, new EventArgs());
        if (eventBeacon == null)
            RaiseUpdateConnected(false);
    }

When debugging I noticed the issue that though there is only one instance of my class(IInterfacedControl) both thread contexts are different and the property values between the two are not the same.

What does "synchronize the property values of calls from similar times" mean?

Could you explain in more details what you are trying to do? Including in the question a minimal demo that reproduces the problematic behavior would be great. You might not even need to bother with interfaces. Just show us your class, its fields, how they should be mutated for your class to work correctly, and how they are actually mutated and cause problems.

And "synchronize the whole class that is IInterfacedControl to keep the variables updated across all threads"?

It's not clear what you want to achieve, some read/write operations (or they sequences) -
pieces of code -  are usually synchronized to ensure predictable outcome, not just properties. It strongly depends on what how you update your state or whatever, ie we need more code.

Your code is doing somethings that I wouldn't pass in a code review. You need to post a [mcve] to give us enough code to refactor.

What is the service, the LogService or the Logger? Don't make us guess. You can remove from your code anything that is not related to the problem, so that we focus on what is important. Catching errors and logging them with the Logger most likely isn't. That's why you hear people asking for minimal demos.
